# Jasmine and Karma with Jasmine gives different results

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, webstorm

I recently started to learn unit testing with Jasmine in JavaScript. Right now I am working in WebStorm, using Karma test runner. When my test on Jasmine by console, and by Karma/Jasmine in WebStorm, some of results differ.

For example, when I create project with simplified structure as below:

```
.
├── _js
|   └── script.js
├── _test
|   └── test.js
├── karma.conf.js
└── index.html
```

## script.js

```
function Card(figure, color) {
    "use strict";

    var that = this;
    this.figure = figure;
    this.color = color;
    this.toString = function () {
        return that.col + that.fig;
    };
}
```

## test.js

```
describe("The validation of name", function () {

    it("should return true if object is properly initialized", function () {
        var a = new Card(1,"A");
        expect(a.figure === 1)
    });

    it("should return true if array contain card", function () {
        var a = [new Card(1,"A"),new Card(1,"B"),new Card(1,"C"),new Card(1,"D")];
        console.log(a);
        expect(a).toContain({figure: 1, color: "A"});
    });
})
```

## karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['js/*.js', 'test/*.js'],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Firefox'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

When I run those tests on Jasmine([HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3VuGs/390/) on JSFiddle), it passes, but in WebStorm it fails, with:

> [Card{figure: 1, color: 'A', toString: function () { ... }},
>   Card{figure: 1, color: 'B', toString: function () { ... }},
>   Card{figure: 1, color: 'C', toString: function () { ... }},
>   Card{figure: 1, color: 'D', toString: function () { ... }}]
>
> Expected [ NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ] to contain Object({ figure: 1, color:
>   'A' }).   @test/test.js:10:9
>     [3]http://localhost:9877/context.js:151:7

It prints proper values from console.log, but test fails and as shown above, objects are treated as NaN.

Whats more, if I create same object, without `new` keyword, by literal object notation, all test pass without problem. So it seems that constructor is a problem here.

What could be cause of such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test will not pass.

Because `toContain` checks all objects to contain defined attributes.

So You've to write Your custom matcher.

Check this example:

```js
// source code
function Card(figure, color) {
  "use strict";

  var that = this;
  this.figure = figure;
  this.color = color;
  this.toString = function () {
    return that.color + that.figure;
  };
}

var customMatchers = {
  hasObjectInArrayThatContains : function(expected){
    var arrayOfObjects = this.actual;
    // iterating array of objects and finding at least
    // one cituation where it passes test
    for(var i in arrayOfObjects) {
      var failures = 0;
      for(var key in expected) {
        if(arrayOfObjects[i][key] != expected[key]) {
          failures++;
        }
      }
      
      if(failures == 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  } 
};

describe("The validation of name", function () {
  
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers(customMatchers); // attaching our custom matchers
  });
  
  it("should return true if object is properly initialized", function () {
    var a = new Card(1,"A");
    expect(a.figure === 1)
  });

  it("should return true if array contain card", function () {
    var a = [new Card(1,"A"),new Card(1,"B"),new Card(1,"C"),new Card(1,"D")];
    expect(a).hasObjectInArrayThatContains({figure: 1, color: "A"}); // using our custom method
  });
});


// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```

and failing example:

see: `expect(a).hasObjectInArrayThatContains({figure: 1, color: "E"})`

```js
// source code
function Card(figure, color) {
  "use strict";

  var that = this;
  this.figure = figure;
  this.color = color;
  this.toString = function () {
    return that.color + that.figure;
  };
}

var customMatchers = {
  hasObjectInArrayThatContains : function(expected){
    var arrayOfObjects = this.actual;
    // iterating array of objects and finding at least
    // one cituation where it passes test
    for(var i in arrayOfObjects) {
      var failures = 0;
      for(var key in expected) {
        if(arrayOfObjects[i][key] != expected[key]) {
          failures++;
        }
      }
      
      if(failures == 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  } 
};

describe("The validation of name", function () {
  
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers(customMatchers); // attaching our custom matchers
  });
  
  it("should return true if object is properly initialized", function () {
    var a = new Card(1,"A");
    expect(a.figure === 1)
  });

  it("should return true if array contain card", function () {
    var a = [new Card(1,"A"),new Card(1,"B"),new Card(1,"C"),new Card(1,"D")];
    expect(a).hasObjectInArrayThatContains({figure: 1, color: "E"}); // using our custom method
  });
});


// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3VuGs/396/

also read this: [testing Your js with Jasmine](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine--net-21229)

Comment: But then, why test pass when I run it by console with jasmine-node? and in linked jsfiddle?

Comment: In jsfiddle You were using jasmine v.1.3.1, so reason can be versions of jasmine and differencies of contains function.